# Customizing color range in image.plot in R

Tags: r, plot, colors

Is there a way to plot values above the zlim cutoff in the image.plot() function?  Here's an example:

```
library('gplots')
library('fields')
library('RColorBrewer')

rf <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))   # make colors
r <- rf(64)

z <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
z[1,1] <- .15
z[2, ] <- .10
z[3, ] <- .05

image.plot(z,
           col = r,
           zlim = c(0, .10))
```

This code produce this image:

[image]

I'd like it if the lower left corner (.15) was colored red (like the .10).  But I couldn't find a way to do that with image.plot() function.

I should mention that need the legend.  Also, the real data is much larger. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick hack, just repeat the final color a few extra times in the color ramp, making the color ramp "flat" in that region. As a result, the highest `z` values will all have the same color:

```
library('gplots')
library('fields')
library('RColorBrewer')

# Original 11 colors
cols = rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral'))

# Repeat the 11th color an extra 5 times
cols = c(cols,rep(cols[11],5))

rf <- colorRampPalette(cols)   # make colors
r <- rf(64)

z <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
z[1,1] <- .15
z[2, ] <- .10
z[3, ] <- .05

image.plot(z, col = r, zlim = c(0, .15))
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Per your comment, the easiest way to get the legend the way you want it, is probably to just change all values greater than 0.1 to 0.1 (or whatever your z-cutoff is) before plotting (`z[z>0.1]=0.1`). Then you can just use your original code.

However, in case there's some reason you don't want to do that, here's a solution (well, a hack anyway) to get z values above the cutoff plotted, while only showing the legend for values below the cutoff. First, run the code above. Then, the code below "covers" the legend with a filled white rectangle and adds a new legend with the desired value range.

Note that in the solution below, the color-to-value mapping in the 0-0.15 color ramp won't in general *exactly* match that of the 0-0.1 color ramp, but you can get them pretty close by tweaking the number of times you repeat the final color in the first color ramp. To get an exact match, I think you could use the `colorRamp` function to map specific colors to specific z-values.

```
# Cover legend
rect(1.3,-1,1.6,2, col="white", border="white", xpd=TRUE)

# Go back to original 11 colors for color ramp
cols = rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral'))
rf <- colorRampPalette(cols)   # make colors
r <- rf(64)

# Plot only the legend with z cutoff at 0.10
image.plot(z, col = r, zlim = c(0, .10), legend.only=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but then that throws off the legend.  If you can find a way to shrink the legend to show only values 0-.10, then you have a working solution.